# Force of interest for simple interest

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finance

I am struggling to work out what the force of interest for simple interest is when using differential equations. I know that it is $\delta=\frac{r}{1+rt}$ where $r$ is the interest rate, but when I try to find the force of interest using differential equations I get a different answer.

Simple interest has accumulation function $a(t)=1+rt$. By definition the force of interest $\delta(t)$ is $\delta(t)=\frac{da(t)/dt}{a(t)}$, so clearly we have that $\delta(t)=r/(1+rt)$.

However, $\frac{da(t)}{dt}=a(t)\delta(t)$ is a differential equation, and solving it we have $a(t)=e^{t\delta}$ (we can assume that the constant is $0$ when integrating, and that $\delta$ is constant).

> Then we have $1+rt=e^{t\delta}$, so $\delta=\frac{1}{t}\ln(1+rt)$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do you assume $\delta (t)$ is constant when it is not constant?

Comment: Oh. Yeah, okay. I was assuming it was constant because you can assume that when thinking about compound interest. Thanks.

Comment: Is it then even possible to solve it this way? Because you need to know how it -the function you are trying to find- integrates...hmm...

Comment: So are you trying to go the opposite way: given $\delta (t)$, obtain $a(t)$?

Comment: No - given $a(t)$ I wand to find $\delta(t)$. I can do it by just differentiating $a(t)$, but I would like to be able to do it using differential equations. Because...because it must be possible and I cannot work out how to.

Comment: If you are talking about the differential equation $\frac{da(t)}{dt} = a(t)\ \delta(t)$ and you hope to find $\delta(t)$, then I am afraid you would have to differentiate $a(t)$ and divide that by $a(t)$...

Comment: Ah well, thanks anyway. If you write up your point about my wrong assumption I'll accept your answer. (And thanks for pointing that out - it has been annoying me all day!)

Comment: Actually you have figured that out: you proved by contradiction that $\delta(t)$ cannot be a constant in the case of simple interest.